# Standalone libC alternatives for kernels on x86?

Tags: libraries

There are a great number of {tiny|micro|little}libc implementations on the web. Most of these are targeted at embedded systems with limited resources. I am working on developing a simple bootable runtime for x86 and just need some of the basic libc utilities like: snprintf, mem*, str*, etc.

I am effectively trying to do what the Linux kernel has done to satisfy its need for libc-like functionality. Without going through the trouble of stripping this from the Linux source, are there open implementations that may satisfy this need?

Comment: uClibc https://www.uclibc.org supports i386

Comment: Also [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/)